# ¿Qué es lo mejor para cancelar requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript

He estado investigando, y existen dos opciones para cancelar requestAnimationFrame: utilizar una bandera que si está a `false` no ejecuta el request, o guardar el requestAnimationFrame en una variable y utilizar cancelAnimationFrame. Aunque ambos códigos hacen lo mismo, Quiero implementar el codigo que cuente con mejor  optimización, funcionalidad, rendimiento y evasión de errores o cuellos de botella, ¿Existe alguna sustento que ayude a determinar cual implementar?

Aporto ejemplo utilizando una bandera:

```js
//Variable con un valor aleatorio y una bandera de stop
var x = 0, stop = false;

function update(){
  //Imprime el valor
  console.log(x, stop);

  //Verifica la detención
  if(!stop){
    interval = requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }

  //AUmenta el valor de x
  x++;
  
  //Verifica si x es mayor que 5
  if(x >= 5){
    //En ese caso, no continua
    stop = true;
  }
}

update();
```

El siguiente ejemplo utilizando `cancelAnimationFrame()`:

```js
//Variable con un valor aleatorio y una bandera de stop
var x = 0, stop = false;

function update(){
  //Guarda la actualización
  interval = requestAnimationFrame(update);

  //Imprime el valor
  console.log(x, stop);

  //Verifica la detención
  if(stop){
    cancelAnimationFrame(interval);
  }

  //AUmenta el valor de x
  x++;
  
  //Verifica si x es mayor que 5
  if(x >= 5){
    //En ese caso, no continua
    stop = true;
  }
}

update();
```

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: No tomes personal lo que se menciona en los comentarios. Todos aportamos al sitio tanto preguntando, respondiendo, o moderando. Los comentarios son para mejorar o corregir la pregunta, no para atacar. La pregunta es interesante, pero necesita replantearse como para que encaje en el formato del sitio.

Comment: @Programando mira el [código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct), saludos.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev muchas gracias

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 ya está actualizada con ejemplos. ¿Es así? Disculpa

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Ok, ¿no existe posibilidad de reapertura o hay que esperar a un tiempo de revisión? Ahora con eso aportado está en revisión ¿pero de quién?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 ¿y quién lo puede reabrir? Ya está modificado ¿la respuesta sería válida ahora?

Comment: @Programando los miembros de la comunidad que cuenten con el privilegio o un moderador diamantado.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Ok, muchas gracias, lo acabo de ver y aceptar. Gracias por tu tiempo y disculpa las molestias. Estaba exasperado con muchas cosas. Perdona de nuevo

Comment: @Programando No te preocupes, muchos de nosotros, incluyéndome a mí, pasamos por esto hace un par de años... y lo creas o no, no es solo ayudar dando respuestas, también estamos los que nos dedicamos a evaluar las preguntas. y darles seguimiento para que sea útil para más personas.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Ok, gracias por la comprensión

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cancelAnimationFrame se utiliza para cancelar la animación desde fuera de la funcion de dicha animación.

El único motivo de que le daría a la función **cancelAnimationFrame** es en caso que un factor externo a dicha animación requiera detener la animación.

Por ejemplo, imagine que ha programado un juego de apostar en el que consiste en hacer girar una ruleta. El usuario debe poder detener el giro de la ruleta; ya sea con un botón o alguna otra acción; al ejecutar dicha acción del usuario, se llama al método **cancelAnimationFrame** y detiene inmediatamente la animación.

Por otro lado, imagine que tiene un slider de imagenes las cuales puede; con el dedo del usuario en dispositivos tactiles, o bien con el puntero; arrastrar dicho slider y "aventarlo"; ahí podría ejecutar su animación y dentro de la función realizar una validación en la que si la velocidad del slider es mayor a X(cualquier nombre de variable) ejecute el método **requestAnimationFrame**, caso contrario no ejecutarlo y la animación se detiene.

Le doy estos dos ejemplos porque los he usado en alguno de mis proyectos. Ambas formas funcionan, pero ambos son situacionales.

Use el que mejor se adapte a su necesidad.

Comment: Y si es para cambiar de una animación a otra es preferible utilizar cancelAnimation y llamar a otra, porque con una bandera puede dar problemas de sincronización, no?

Comment: En ese caso te recomendaría usar **cancelAnimationFrame** e iniciar una nueva animación, hacer la validación dentro de la animación sería muy catastrofico, ya que estaría validando un aproximado de 60 veces por segundo algo que es inpredecible, ya que depende de una acción externa. Aunque sea un poco más de código, es más limpio y más eficiente :3

Comment: muchas gracias, solucionado

Answer (score 0):

Es mejor la asignación de una variable y utilizar el cancelAnimationFrame porque para una solicitud de animación específica y si utilizas un flag puede ser menos preciso y puede llevar a problemas de sincronización. Por ejemplo, si hay varias solicitudes de animación pendientes y se establece la bandera en `false`, es posible que algunas de las solicitudes de animación aún se ejecuten antes de que se procese la bandera y cuál entonces se pararía, vete por lo seguro, asigna la variable y usa el cancelAnimationFrame.

Comment: Si una pregunta se responde con _para mí es mejor_..., entonces es basada en opiniones :)

Comment: Ahora ya no dice "para mí" porque se editó la respuesta @Programando (? Justamente si la respuesta se basa en la experiencia del otro, la pregunta es _basada en opiniones_, ya que cada uno pudo haber tenido una experiencia distinta. Así, para unos será mejor una opción, y para otros, la otra.

Comment: Es que no es necesario ser tan quisquillosos. La experiencia es clave en el desarrollo, sobre todo cuando muchas veces existen varias formas de realizar lo mismo. Incluso cuando la respuesta tiene código involucrado existe una cuota de subjetividad (porque ese código y no otro??). Por lo demás preguntas que invitan a respuestas subjetivas `SI` están permitidas https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask y las respuestas son válidas cuando: "Cualquier respuesta que encamine a los lectores en la dirección correcta ayudará siempre" https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer